# Circular view path [error] while json output expected in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

newbie to Springboot with gradle, I am creating a restful service which queries the db2 database and returns the result in json.

The desired output

```
{
resource: {
results: [
{
currencyCode: "JPY",
conversionRateToUSD: "0.010286580",
conversionRateFromUSD: "97.214040040",
startDate: "2011-01-01",
endDate: "2011-01-29"
}
]
}
}
```

The api i am trying to build is http://localhost:8080/apis/exchange-rates/referenceDate=2015-01-01&currencyCode=JPY

I have created the below  controller class

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/apis")
public class IndividualExchangeRateController {

    @Autowired
    private IndividualExchangeRateService individualExchangeRateService;

    public IndividualExchangeRateController(IndividualExchangeRateService individualExchangeRateService) {
        this.individualExchangeRateService = individualExchangeRateService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/exchange-rates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody IndividualResource getIndividual(@RequestParam("referenceDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD")Date referenceDate,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "currencyCode", required = false) String currencyCode){
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside Controller");
            return individualExchangeRateService.getIndividualExchangeRate(referenceDate, currencyCode);
        }
        catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
            throw new InvalidRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the below error when i call the api

javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Can anybody help out on this ?

As the output is json i do not have thymeleaf dependencies on my application

Below is the gradle build file

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.abc.service'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://artifactory.abcinc.dev/artifactory/maven-repos" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    runtime 'com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc4:4.19.49'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.1.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '3.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.9'
}


public class IndividualExchangeRate {
    private String currencyCode;
    private double conversionRateFromUSD;
    private double conversionRateToUSD;
}

public class IndividualResource {
    private List<IndividualExchangeRate> individualExchangeRates;
}
```

All the classes are annotated with lombok.

Comment: I removed jackson and added thymleaf dependencies and getting the below error now  Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: http://localhost:8080/apis/exchange-rates?referenceDate=2015-01-01&currencyCode=JPY with a `?` in url?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses a default Whitelabel error page in case server error.So there might be some code snippets which is breaking your appliaction flow.

Add `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` in your `application.properties` file .

OR add the following code snippets :

```
@Controller
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController{

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "Error handling";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whitelabel error is expected behavior when url is wrong. And the author's url is wrong. Your solution is kind of needless customizations. And extending `ErrorController` with `RestController` is semantically incorrect as the latter indicates that response body is expected.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/apis/exchange-rates/referenceDate=2015-01-01&currencyCode=JPY , this is also giving the same output

Comment: @TapasKumarPradhan http://localhost:8080/apis/exchange-rates?referenceDate=2015-01-01&currencyCode=JPY

Comment: Figured out the issue ,  public @ResponseBody IndividualResource getIndividual(@RequestParam("referenceDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD")Date referenceDate,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "currencyCode", required = false) String currencyCode) , The issue was iwth datetime format pattern , the pattern it expects is "yyyy-MM-dd" and not "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 0):

error:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Jan 26 14:57:15 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

I have GET request and jsp file with same name , so I changed the name

```
@RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String gotoLogin(    ) {
       return "login";
   }
```

resolved my issue

```
@RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String gotoLogin(    ) {
        return "signin";
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).